# How can I import the OpenDaylight ZIP file into Eclipse?

Tags: opendaylight

I downloaded the OpenDaylight Hydrogen Release Base Edition zip of https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Release/Hydrogen/Base/Installation_Guide. How can I import it into Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Hydrogen has been obsolete for a long time. To get started developing on OpenDaylight with Eclipse, I highly recommend using [the Oomph Eclipse installer](https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup) with OpenDaylight templates. See the linked page for details.

Alternatively, you can follow the manual instructions from [the OpenDaylight development environment setup guide](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup) (and subsequent pages).

Comment: When i trying to install oomph,i get this error:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830416/i-have-problem-with-install-eclipse-installer?noredirect=1#comment94509462_53830416